# Can we use Magmi for Magento EE 1.10.0.1 edition?

Tags: magento, import, cron, version, magmi

Can we use **Magmi** for Magento EE 1.10.0.1 edition as during configuring Magmi, it's asking for Magento version which only provide CE versions like 1.3x,1.4x,1.5x,1.6x...?

If yes, how exactly?
Can anybody explains that in detail?

I have my data I Oracle tables & I can access Oracle & Mysql database through PHP. Now I want to insert data from Oracle to Mysql as I have connection for both...So how can I automate this process of data transfer?
Considering my scenario can Magmi help me to achieve that through Cron jobs...?

Comment: How about asking the Magmi developer? [http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/forums/forum/1228365](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/forums/forum/1228365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento EE 1.10.x is based on 1.5.x CE version. It could work, but test it in staging environment before.

Answer (score 1):

Prat, its works in Magento EE 1.12.0.2 version as well. But you need to take care while putting column header for simple and configurable products.

Product type was not importing for me, so i just tweaked my csv by importing all simple products first and then configurable products.
Simple product shall '_type' column header and 
COnfigurable product shall have 'type' column header.

But it works for me.